# Where should media queries be placed?

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend, media-queries

I'm new to media queries and I want to know Where should they be placed.

At the very bottom of the stylesheet?

In the `<head>` of the HTML linking to different stylesheets e.g phone.css, tablet.css, desktop.css?

Is there a difference between one place and the other one (performance, maintenance)?

Thaks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definite answer as to where you should place your media queries. The important part is that you take an approach that makes your stylesheets maintainable.

One common approach is placing your media queries at the very bottom of your stylesheet, for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#syntax) says that media at-rule may be placed at the top level of your code